# Map reduce with mongodb: _id issues

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, reduce

I have a collection called "events" that looks like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fd89f8d3cbec825d7000001"),
        "type" : "lms_course_view",
        "datetime" : ISODate("2011-12-23T12:55:00Z"),
        "user" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("4fd89f8d3cbec825d7000000")
                }
        ]
}
```

And another one, called "users", as follows:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fd89f8d3cbec825d7000000"),
        "name" : "02ad1046f",

         (...)
}
```

I'm trying to count the number of times each user has produced each event type. I'm trying with map-reduce, but I don't know how to create a map function that iterates over events while emits users' name (stored in a different collection).

Any clue? Is it possible with map-reduce?

Comment: It is possible, but you will have to do two mapreduce, you can find a sample [here](http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/).

Comment: Is there a reason that the user names are not in the events collection?  You might consider denormalizing your schema a bit to add the name to user array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your user's names are stored separately from the `events` collection, you'll need to make two passes anyway.  I recommend using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) and then converting the `user["_id"]` to `user["name"]` in a second pass.  Aggregation framework code might look something like:

```
db.events.aggregate(
    { $unwind: "$user" }, // breaks apart user array into separate documents
    { $group: {
        _id: { user: "$user._id", type: "$type" }
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    } }
);
```

Comment: Great. It works fine. Thank you very much. I didn't know the Aggregation Framework. Actually, I was working with version 2.0 (from ubuntu universe repository).

Answer (score 0):

Your schema seems poorly constructed for your stated use case.

I recommend reconsidering it and denormalizing the user name into the events collection.

I assume that user field is an array because more than one user can be producing each event - in that case it will still be an array but each element would have two fields - _id like it does now plus name representing the name of the user.   This is relatively "safe" since user names don't change very often (if ever).

Once you have that schema, you have a choice of using MapReduce (emitting {user name, event type} as key) or you can use the aggregation framework (in version 2.1+) the way @slee describes in his answer.

Comment: I agree, my schema is poorly constructed for my use case. Anyway, this is what I have, I'll try to make the most of it. As @slee says, I need two passes.